# How to define tasks to run with hprof from sbt 0.10

Tags: scala, settings, sbt, hprof

How do I define "run" and "test:run" tasks to run with hprof on forked JVM.

in build.sbt

```
fork in run := true

javaOptions in run += "-agentlib:hprof"
```

This setting makes both run tasks work with hprof.

I want to define my hprof task for keeping default "run" and "test:run" tasks and use from sbt prompt.

```
//define myHprofTask, alias default run task

fork in myHprofTask := true

javaOptions in myHprofTask += "-agentlib:hprof"
```

How can I define tasks like this?

Answer (score 2):

This is based on the `Additional run tasks` section of https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Common-Tasks.

1. Define the new task key:

   ```
   lazy val myHprofTask = TaskKey[Unit]("my-hprof-task")
   ```
2. Add a new run task in the `Compile` configuration (the `myHprofTask in Compile` part) using the `Compile` classpath that executes `demo.Main`, passing "arg1" and "arg2" as arguments:

   ```
   fullRunTask(myHprofTask in Compile, Compile, "demo.Main", "arg1", "arg2")
   ```
3. Do the same for the `Test` configuration:

   ```
   fullRunTask(myHprofTask in Test, Test, "demo.TestMain", "arg1", "arg2")
   ```
4. Then, you can define the `fork` and `javaOptions` settings as in the question.

Here is the full example using the quick configuration style (`build.sbt`):

```
{
  lazy val myHprofTask = TaskKey[Unit]("my-hprof-task")
  seq(
    fullRunTask(myHprofTask in Compile, Compile, "demo.Main", "arg1"),
    fullRunTask(myHprofTask in Test, Test, "demo.TestMain", "arg1"),
    fork in myHprofTask := true,
    javaOptions in myHprofTask += "-agentlib:hprof"
  )
}
```

Comment: But I want to use the prompt for default run & test:run tasks from own defined task, like: 
    [1] demo.Main1  
    [2] demo.Main2  
    Enter number: